# Querying and filtering on calculated column with eager loading in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have three models with a working Eloquent query that uses eager loading. My models have these relationships:

```
class Template extends Eloquent {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    public function profiles() {
        return $this->hasMany('Profile');
    }
    public function templates() {
        return $this->hasMany('Template');
    }
}

class Profile extends Eloquent {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

And my working query looks like this:

```
$templates = Template::with('user', 'user.profiles')
    ->where('public', '=', true)
    ->whereIn('type', $search_types)
    ->where('user_id', '!=', $user->id)
    ->paginate(8);
```

This seems to be working great, but I need to add one more thing to it, which has been very difficult for me to get right. I need to alter this query to take into account the template user's distance from the current user, using the existing `lat` and `long` columns in the `user` table. I only want the query to return the templates whose users are within 25 miles of the current user (ideally ordering by distance, but that part is optional).

I've attempted to add a custom calculated column to the user relationship like so:

```
$templates = Template::with(array('user' => function($query) use($user) {
        $query->select('*')->selectRaw('(3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(long) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance', array($user->lat, $user->long, $user->lat));
    }, 'user.profiles' => function($query) {
        $query
    }))
    ->where('public', '=', true)
    ->whereIn('type', $search_types)
    ->where('user_id', '!=', $user->id)
    ->having('distance', '<=', 25)
    ->orderBy('distance')
    ->paginate(8);
```

This doesn't work because, with the eager loading, the `distance` column does not exist in the initial query, causing it to fail at the `having` clause. If I move that part into the anonymous function and remove the ordering, it doesn't immediately fail, but it simply ignores distance for the templates query, and then only grabs the related users who are within 25 miles, which doesn't seem that helpful.

What's the proper way to use Eloquent to get the data I'm after?

Comment: Do you have any solution for your case? Is similar to mine and would be great to have some thoughts to get that working with some built in laravel techniques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up with the following (without the optional ordering), which seems to work well enough:

```
$templates = Template::with('user', 'user.profiles')
    ->where('public', '=', true)
    ->whereIn('type', $search_types)
    ->where('user_id', '!=', $user->id)
    ->whereHas('user', function($query) use($user, $distance) {
        $query->whereRaw('(3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(location_lat)) * cos(radians(location_long) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(location_lat)))) <= ?', array($user->location_lat, $user->location_long, $user->location_lat, $distance));
    })
    ->paginate(8);
```

Comment: do you know a way to actually return the 'distance' as a property to each returned user?